# update featured image meta data information in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, api, metadata

I'm creating post in wordpress via external api from my php api. I've been able to create post and set feature image for it, but I need to know on how to update following information :

- image alt text
- image caption
- image title

this question might sound stupid, but I didn't find strong sample for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
if you image file has the meta data, you can use the following function to generate the data automatically.

```
// Define attachment metadata 
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
```

Find more about the variables the above function generates in the following link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata

If the file does not have meta, You have form as an array manually like the following one.

```
$attach_data = array(); 
$attach_data["image_meta"]["caption"] ='';
$attach_data["image_meta"]["title"] ='';
```

You can get an idea about an image's metadata variables in the following link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_image_metadata#Return_Values

Finally update the values as metadata to that attachment.

```
// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attach_data );
```